# Email not delivered using resque on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, resque, rails-activejob

My delayed job for sending an email is queued and processed correctly according to heroku logs but i never actually receive the email. It works as expected locally with the same smtp settings so i don't know what the issue could be.

Here are extracts from the log:

Queueing:

```
2015-08-28T08:46:46.935402+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 9e9e8110-ee2f-4562-9a03-b1f482d56c7c) to Resque(mailers) at 2015-08-28 08:47:46 UTC with arguments: "UserMailer", "thank_you", "deliver_now!", "xxx@gmail.com"
```

Processing:

```
    2015-08-28T08:47:50.912636+00:00 app[scheduler.1]: 2015-08-28 08:47:50 Processing Delayed Items
2015-08-28T08:47:54.637690+00:00 app[worker.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [9e9e8110-ee2f-4562-9a03-b1f482d56c7c] Performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Resque(mailers) with arguments: "UserMailer", "thank_you", "deliver_now!", "xxx@gmail.com"
2015-08-28T08:47:54.658354+00:00 app[worker.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [9e9e8110-ee2f-4562-9a03-b1f482d56c7c]   Rendered user_mailer/thank_you.html.erb within layouts/mailer (2.7ms)
2015-08-28T08:47:55.294365+00:00 app[worker.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [9e9e8110-ee2f-4562-9a03-b1f482d56c7c] Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Resque(mailers) in 656.38ms
2015-08-28T08:47:54.932032+00:00 app[worker.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [9e9e8110-ee2f-4562-9a03-b1f482d56c7c]
2015-08-28T08:47:54.932073+00:00 app[worker.1]: UserMailer#thank_you: processed outbound mail in 290.2ms
```

SMTP settings in production.rb and development.rb:

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp


 # SMTP settings for gmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port                 => 587,
   :user_name            => ENV['gmail_username'],
   :password             => ENV['gmail_password'],
   :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution:

Go to http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click continue (this will grant access for 10 minutes for registering new apps). After this my app in production started sending emails ;)